# Labels of the authors in elsarticle

Tags: elsarticle

I have an issue with labeling the authors in `elsarticle`.

What I wish to have is like this:

[image]

So, people belonging to the same address (college), the label must appear separated by commas in the next line. But I get like this:

[image]

How do I achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\journal{Journal name}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{XXX}
\author[label1]{Dr. Thirumanaran M., Subham Soni}
\address[label1]{Department of Computer Science and Engineering, Pondicherry Engg College, India}
\begin{abstract}
\kant[1]
\end{abstract}
\begin{keyword}
Interactive Voice Response System \sep Dynamic \sep Context-based \sep Semantic Web Services \sep Rule Engine \sep JESS \sep Ontology
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use `\thanks{}` instead of `address` and maybe `\notefootmark[]`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like it thinks that "Dr. Thirumanaran M., Subham Soni" is a single author. Try declaring them separately as authors:

```
\author[label1]{Dr. Thirumanaran M.}
\author[label1]{Subham Soni}
\address[label1]{Department of Computer Science and Engineering, Pondicherry Engg College, India}
```

This should list both authors separately, and each will have the footnote number corresponding to the Pondicherry Engg College. Note that each affiliation will only have a single footnote number or letter. Multiple authors can share the same footnote index referencing the same institution. Each author does not automatically get an individual footnote number.